# $this->input->post() and $_POST is NULL in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, post, codeigniter-3

I am getting a problem in codeigniter where i have a view file called view.php.

```
  <?php echo form_open('');?>
  <table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

     <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo form_input('fullname1',$row_data['fullname']);?>  </td>
      <td><?php echo form_input('username1',$row_data['username']);?></td>
         <td><?php echo anchor("welcome/save/".$row_data['rid'],form_button('button',"Save"));?></td>
  </tr>

    </tbody
   </table>
  <?php echo form_close();?>
```

and here is my save method

```
public function save($rid){
    $arr=array('fullname'=>$this->input->post('fullname1'),
                'username'=>$this->input->post('username1')
        );
        var_dump($_POST);
        var_dump($arr);
```

}

both array varable giving me NULL values while the textboxes have the values   Please Help.... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the url to your form_open method. Try

```
echo form_open("your_url");
```

give the path of your save method instead of your_url.
Also check documentation [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

The form_open method demands a target url.

Answer (score 0):

**In View**

```
 # Syntax <?php echo form_open('controllerName/MethodName');?>
 <?php echo form_open('welcome/save');?>

// remove this
<td><?php echo anchor("welcome/save/".$row_data['rid'],form_button('button',"Save"));?></td>

// Add this
 echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!');
```

**In Controller**

```
public function save(){
    $fullname= $this->input->post('fullname1');
    $username = $this->input->post('username1');

    echo "MY name is ".$fullname." UserName Is : "$username;
}
```

**Read [Form Helper Codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) and [form-validation-using-codeigniter example](http://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/)**

Comment: its working this way. thanks. but if i need to pass one argument to save method which is the "id" then how can i send the id to method.?????

Comment: **past it with hidden field**

Comment: Like this `form_hidden('id', '123');`